# Get column value of a row if it matches other column value from other row

Tags: python, pandas

Same as [Get column value if it matches another column value in the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60019276/get-column-value-if-it-matches-another-column-value-in-the-same-table) but with Python/pandas than with SQL because the query takes too long to run.

I have a df with:

```
Id   | replyId | commentID_parentID | usernameChannelId | channelId
1    | NULL    | NULL               | a                 | g
2    | NULL    | NULL               | b                 | k
NULL | 1.k     | 1                  | a                 | p
NULL | 1.p     | 1                  | c                 | i
3    | NULL    | NULL               | d                 | h
NULL | 2.k     | 2                  | g                 | g
```

and a table with channels like:

I want to know which user (userChannelId) replied to which user.

So I take a row with a comment and check if:

```
Id == NULL? Then it's a reply -> get userChannelId where commentID_parentID == Id
Id != NULL? Then it's a main comment -> userChannelId replied to channelId
```

And result should be:

```
userChannelId_Source | userChannelId_Target
a                    | g
b                    | k
a                    | a
c                    | a
g                    | b
```

Comment "d" has no entry where commentID_parentID == Id so it's left out.

My code so far:

```
cm["usernameChannelId_reply"] = None

for row in cm.itertuples():
    if cm.commentID_parentID is None: # comment is a main comment
        cm.at[row.Index, 'usernameChannelId_reply'] = cm.channelId
    else: # comment is a reply comment
        temp = cm.loc[cm.Id == row.commentID_parentID]["usernameChannelId"][0]
        #temp = cm.query("Id == commentID_parentID").head(1).loc[:, 'usernameChannelId']
        print(temp)
        if len(set(temp)) == 0:
            print(0, row.Index)
            #cm.at[row.Index, 'usernameChannelId_reply'] = temp
        else:
            cm.at[row.Index, 'usernameChannelId_reply'] = temp
```

But I get a

> KeyError: 0

Removing the [0] prints e.g:

> 997    UCOYb6iKhuCHKDwvd_iBnIBw Name: usernameChannelId, dtype: object

Comment: you say "d" is left out, but I don't see the difference between this row and the first two rows?

Comment: Which row do you mean with "this row"?

Comment: The structure of the row with d in usernameChannelId looks like the first row, so why the row with d is removed?

Comment: if it takes to long in SQL i doubt it will be quicker in Python.. have you optimised your data/table/query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you want to map the values in commentID_parentID with the values of usernameChannelId associated to the same Id. You can try:

```
#create the mapper
s_map = df.loc[df.Id.ne('NULL'), :].set_index(['Id'])['usernameChannelId']

# create the column by mapping the values where comment_parentID is not NULL, otherwise channelID
df['userChannelId_Target'] = np.where( df['commentID_parentID'].ne('NULL'), 
                                       df['commentID_parentID'].map(s_map), df['channelId'])

# see result
print (df[['usernameChannelId', 'userChannelId_Target' ]])
  usernameChannelId userChannelId_Target
0                 a                    g
1                 b                    k
2                 a                    a
3                 c                    a
4                 d                    h
5                 g                    b
```